# Filling null values in multiple dataframe columns based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I wrote a function that fills any null values in 2 dataframe columns baded on a condition being met. I've written unit tests, they all work.

When running it on actual data, it sometimes leads to a `ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value`

I'm confused because my unit tests pass. The code is essentially this:
`df.loc[df['column'].isin(column_values_to_update), ['col2', 'col3']] = df[['col2', 'col3']].fillna(0)`

It works when `column_values_to_update` is empty, it works when its full...yet when running on certain datasets, I get the ValueError and I'm not sure why....I've reset the index before getting to this point and no luck.

Anyone have any idea why sometimes this error can arise, and sometimes it doesn't? Let me know if you need more info...

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you running? The above really *should* work. The issue is probably that the RHS is a longer Series than the LHS, but `pandas` really should be smart enough to align on the index (and a duplicated Index would give a different error than you're seeing). If you want to be explicit, you can change the RHS to  also include the mask `= df.loc[df['column'].isin(column_values_to_update),['col2', 'col3']].fillna(0)`, which might fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in the end I solved the issue by adding an if clause where I use .loc only if `column_values_to_update` (which is a Set) is not empty.

I'm still baffled because my unit tests where `column_values_to_update` was empty still passed.....

oh well